# Numpy - summing ndarray values based on conditional indexing

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

first question here. This is not easy to explain, so I'll give an example.
I am pretty new to Numpy.
I have a 2 dimentional array of 2048 columns x 100 lines (raw image, read by CV2)
I would like to sum / create a new array contains only the values of the indexes of x8 separately.

example:

```
sum[0] = matrix[0][0] + matrix[0][8] + matrix[0][16] + ... + matrix[2040][100]
sum[1] = matrix[0][1] + matrix[0][9] + matrix[0][17] + ... + matrix[2041][100]
sum[2] = matrix[0][2] + matrix[0][10] + matrix[0][18] + ... + matrix[2042][100]
         .
         .
sum[7] = matrix[0][7] + matrix[0][15] + matrix[0][23] + ... + matrix[2047][100]
```

I do believe there is a nice way for doing it on arrays using Numpy without for loops.
Does anyone knows how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: After you reach the end of the first line, do you want to keep taking every 8th value while starting at the beginning of the second line?

Comment: Yes. Every line is 2048 pixels, 100 lines.

Comment: `matrix.ravel(i::8].sum() for i in range(8)]`